# Crash on objc_release

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've got a strange crash on objc_release. The program has been analyzed with Instruments, recording all allocations. The invalid address that the program tries to access is not recorded anywhere. I assume that's the cause no NSZombie objects appear.

I don't use the autoreleasepool for my own allocations.

Any idea how I could trace back the source of the problem?

```
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000114208650

VM Regions Near 0x114208650:
    Stack                  00000001140ba000-000000011413c000 [  520K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  thread 11
-->
    MALLOC_LARGE           00000001144ba000-0000000114d2f000 [ 8660K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8a3280e6 objc_release + 22
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8a32765a (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 502
2   liboainject.dylib               0x00000001083da2c8 __oa__objc_autoreleasePoolPop + 123
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90beb9e2 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 50
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff88c05e17 -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 147
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e0dba68 -[NSApplication run] + 725
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e0c67a3 NSApplicationMain + 940
7   com.xxxx.xxxxxxx                0x0000000108102ea2 main + 34 (main.mm:5)
8   com.xxxx.xxxxxxx                0x00000001080e9a84 start + 52
```

Comment: Are you using manual memory allocation or ARC?

Comment: I'm using manual memory allocation. ARC is turned off.

Comment: Are you saying you enabled zombies, and that didn't work? Are you running the Zombies instrument?

Comment: Yes, I had zombies enabled but none were found. Then I tried the Allocations template in Instruments to check the address shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Problem: I subclassed NSView in a dynamically loaded library.

Solution: Create the subclass during runtime (with the objc runtime) and assign a unique name to it. Ugly code, but it works.